# How to remove extra red space in Container?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im using bottomNavigationBar Widget  in Scaffold Widget but  I have extra red Container that cover some area of Scaffold as you see in the attachment . How to remove red area of Container ? I tried to use Colors.transparent but its not work !

try it in codepen :
[Click Here](https://codepen.io/khalifa007/pen/LYNpWgN)

Attachment :

[image]

Full Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Color(0xff2c3e50),
      bottomNavigationBar: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
print('Hi');
          },
          child: Container(
            color:Colors.red,
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(
                      0xFF1D1E33,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(2),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(2),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'heello ? ',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just remove the container with red color.

Comment: @Mobina I tried but it go defult value which will be Colors.white  in Mobile simulation  , in  codepen its work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove:

```
color:Colors.red,
```

in line 21.

Or replace this line to:

```
color:Colors.transparent,
```

Like this:
https://codepen.io/Fudal/pen/YzqyVGE

Comment: great its work in codepen but in Mobile simulation didint work becuase its go to defult value which will be Colors.white in Mobile simulation